# How to load custom UIView from xib using Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

The task is to create custom UIView that loads UI from .xib file using Swift. How do I do that?

I tried to do that using the code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {

var view: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]

    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}

}
```

It runs, but crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and shows me the message:

```
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

Actually, I need to translate code given here http://qnoid.com/2013/03/20/How-to-implement-a-reusable-UIView.html to Swift 2.0, but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Try

```
let yourView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("youViewNibName", owner: self, options: nil).first as! YourView
```

Do it in your **ViewController class**, then you can access the view in required init with coder, where you should call `xibSetup()`.

Comment: I need to create designable view, that renders in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct, that your class is called **CustomView** and you're loading **CustomView.xib** where the class for the view in xib is **CustomView**?

If that is so you probably do not understand what you're doing

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but I don't see a problem. I used this solution http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6 It is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Just checked it on github, note in its CustomView.xib class CustomView is not denoted as a class for any of the views

Comment: Otherwise with the situation above, you're getting into loop